# How to implement all members of an interface using CodeGenerator

Tags: c#, visual-studio, code-generation, roslyn, visual-studio-extensions

I am creating a Visual Studio Extension, in which on executing certain command, a .cs file should be generated with a class implementing an Interface and all the members should be automatically implemented as well.

Example:

Suppose I have following interface,

```
interface IFile
{
    void ReadFile();
    void WriteFile(string text);
}
```

And I want to generate following code:

```
using System;

namespace TestProject
{
    public class FileInfo : IFile
    {
        public void ReadFile()
        {
            
        }

        public void WriteFile(string text)
        {
            
        }
    }
}
```

But All I am able to generate is following:

```
using System;

namespace TestProject
{
    public class FileInfo : IFile
    {
    }
}
```

Code Written to generate above code is as below:

```
AdhocWorkspace adhocWorkspace = new AdhocWorkspace();
var syntaxGenerator = SyntaxGenerator.GetGenerator(adhocWorkspace, LanguageNames.CSharp);

var usingSystem = syntaxGenerator.NamespaceImportDeclaration("System");

var interfaceNode = new List<SyntaxNode>() { SyntaxFactory.ParseTypeName("IFile") };

var classDeclaration = syntaxGenerator.ClassDeclaration("FileInfo",
    null,
    Accessibility.Public,
    DeclarationModifiers.None,
    null,
    interfaceNode,
    null
    );

var namespaceDeclaration = syntaxGenerator.NamespaceDeclaration("TestProject", classDeclaration);

var generatedCode = syntaxGenerator.CompilationUnit(usingSystem, namespaceDeclaration)
    .NormalizeWhitespace().ToFullString();
```

How can I implement all the members using CodeGenerator?
Or Is there a command which I can use like the command to Format the Document as below

```
dte.ExecuteCommand("Edit.FormatDocument", string.Empty);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SyntaxGenerator.MethodDeclaration Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.editing.syntaxgenerator.methoddeclaration?view=roslyn-dotnet-3.9.0#Microsoft_CodeAnalysis_Editing_SyntaxGenerator_MethodDeclaration_System_String_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable_Microsoft_CodeAnalysis_SyntaxNode__System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable_System_String__Microsoft_CodeAnalysis_SyntaxNode_Microsoft_CodeAnalysis_Accessibility_Microsoft_CodeAnalysis_Editing_DeclarationModifiers_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable_Microsoft_CodeAnalysis_SyntaxNode__), which is like:

```
var cloneMethoDeclaration = generator.MethodDeclaration("ReadFile", 
    null, 
    null, 
    null, 
    Accessibility.Public, 
    DeclarationModifiers.None, 
    null);
```

And I also found [a sample from github](https://gist.github.com/jagt/1b77a3c6e2c0ba2aea1ca437997289f2), hope it can help you.

Comment: This is manual method. Manually generating all the members of an interface.

Comment: If you want to auto implement a interface, maybe you can create a snippet or modify the existing snippet file through vs extension.